# how to center div with a class

Tags: html

I have a div that already has a class and an id:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="images/go.jpg" class="hover" />
    <p class="text"> <a href="start.html"> Start your adventure</a> </p>
</div>
```

I am using this to create an image rollover that causes a link to become visible when moused over. However, for one of the images, specifically the one i copied in,  I want to center it. How can i center it without losing the id?

Comment: Set the margins on each side equal- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally?rq=1

Comment: I'm a little confused, do I copy in the margin code into '#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}
' or in #wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
} ?

Comment: Put that code into whatever element you want to center.

Comment: So, if I want the picture and the text (as i'm using a rollover effect) to show up properly, I want to put the margin code into both?

Comment: Yes, or why not in `div#wrapper`?

Answer (score 1):

Apply "margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto" to your css rule. For example:

```
.hover {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That caused the text to be centered within the picture- which I certainly wanted, but thought I couldn't do, but now I want one of the pictures (so I'm not sure if I want to edit the css, which would cause everyone of them to do that) to be centered on the webpage

Comment: Add another class to your img tag: for example adding ".center-image" like <img class="hover center-image"/>. Then create a .center-hover rule that applies the margins. Use the center-image class only on the image you want to center.

Comment: `#wrapper:hover .text {
margin: 0 auto;
visibility:visible;
}

#wrapper:hover .hover-center {
margin: 0 auto;
visibility:visible; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;} ` is what i have for my CSS rule- and I set my html img tag to hover-center for the class, but it didn't seem to do anything. (The top being the one that is for every other image)

Comment: You probably need to apply a width: and display:block to the hover-center, where width is the width of your image.